# Disabling cache still sends Cache-Control: no-cache in the request

Tags: google-chrome, http, browser-cache, cache-control

Why does checking "Disable cache" in Developer Tools cause `Cache-Control: no-cache` to be sent in the request?

`no-cache` means check with the server to see if the cached copy is the same as what's on the server, if it is, use that, if not, then get the new version.

But, if the cache is disabled, then the client has to request a new version from the server regardless.

So why does it bother sending `no-cache`?

Also, isn't `no-cache` pointless without also sending `If-None-Match`? Otherwise the server has no way of knowing what version of the file is in your cache.

I guess there is no cached version so it can't send the `ETag` in the `If-None-Match`, which brings me back to the original question of why `no-cache` is used at all.

[image]

After clearing the cache, unchecking the "Disable cache" checkbox, and refreshing the page, you can see no `Cache-Control` header is sent:

[image]

Comment: see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64139
and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28035

Comment: there is much more going on in the browser code, to think of, for example, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161725#c18

Comment: also, some files might be under a CDN, which cached them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `no-cache` means check with the server to see if the cached copy is the same as what's on the server, if it is, use that, if not, then get the new version.

`no-cache` [means](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.4): "a cache MUST NOT use a stored response to satisfy the request without successful validation on the origin server." It doesn't require a conditional request, a regular `GET` would also satisfy that definition.

> So why does it bother sending `no-cache`?

To prevent intermediate caches from returning a cached version without validation.

> Also, isn't `no-cache` pointless without also sending `If-None-Match`? Otherwise the server has no way of knowing what version of the file is in your cache.

The browser is not making a conditional request (though it could), so it doesn't use `If-None-Match`. An intermediate cache, though, could have a cached version with an `ETag`, which it could revalidate. Or not.

I think the point you're missing is that this directive is directed at intermediate caches, to control their behavior.

Comment: If `no-cache` is sent by the browser, but with no `If-None-Match`, then it's instructing the intermediate cache to forward the request to the server, sending `If-None-Match: <etag>` in the forwarded request to the server, if it has a cached copy?

Why does unchecking "Disable cache" in Dev Tools stop the `no-cache` directive being sent?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: If you uncheck "Disable cache" you're returning to normal caching behavior, so why would the browser send `no-cache`?

Comment: Good point, thanks for clearing that up. Btw when you say "It doesn't require a conditional request, a regular GET would also satisfy that definition.", this seems to contradict what is in https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/ where it describes pattern 2 as "always server-revalidated", but you're implying the browser is free to just not use the cache and download straight from the server? What determines which path the browser takes?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner: Caching is entirely optional in HTTP, so no client is forced to make conditional requests. That said, I assume browsers would always make conditional requests if they can, except in certain abnormal circumstances (like checking *Disable cache*, apparently).